# LIMIT is slowing down query significantly

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a parquet I read from disk (20,000 partitions) and the display command `df.display()` returns almost right away, whereas `df.limit(1).display()` literally takes hours to execute. I don't understand what is going on here. It is also not only the `display()` command that is slow, but also a join I would actually like to perform. By contrast, `df.show(n=1)` returns almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Limit()` runs per partition first, then combines the result into a final result. Since there are 20,000 partitions in your data this takes a lot of time to execute.

One solution to still use `limit()` is to reduce the number of partitions as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455123/19261326) answer with: `df.coalesce(1).limit(1).display()`. But this is not recommended as all the data will be sent to the driver, and may cause out of memory exception.

Comment: Any way I could tell pyspark to only consider a single partition? This is really annoying for prototyping the pipeline.

Comment: @giantsqueed, I am trying to understand here, you already said that `show()` works instantaneously. Any reason you **have** to use `limit()`? If it is to take intermediate data and write for example, can you try `take(1)` or `first()` like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832394/spark-access-first-n-rows-take-vs-limit). Both use `limit()` internally but due to the implementations it could be faster.